# How do you do an intelligent redirect at the sub-site and site collection level?

Tags: site-collection, redirect

I need to migrate an entire site collection to another site collection. For various reasons, this process could take several days. We plan to migrate one sub-site at a time. While this process is going on, I would like to do an intelligent redirect.

For example: http://mycompany/sites/**SC1**/mypage.aspx?x=123 will redirect to http://mycompany/sites/**SC2**/mypage.aspx?x=123.

I know how to do this at the IIS level for a web application but haven't found a way to do it at the site collection or sub-site level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible with very popular and widely used Add-on for IIS - the Url Rewriter. You can install it using Web Platform Installer. Here are some quick starts for you:

http://johnliu.net/blog/2010/7/23/sharepoint-2010-with-iis-url-rewrite-20.html

http://blog.mastykarz.nl/friendly-urls-sharepoint-site-4-steps-iis7-url-rewrite-module/

Looks like you may need to write as many rules as sub sites. A redirection rule can be added for a sub site when it is migrated.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for.